# Migrating .DBF files into Sql Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbf

I have some DBF files in FOxPro 9.0 But I want to migrate the data from DBF to sql server, what should I do? Can anybody provide me script or Stored Procedure to migarte the data?
Also, I want to know that is it possible to convert the data in DBF files into SQL server database?
Also, I dont know about OLE Db. Is it important for the migration? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

From within VFP, have you looked into the top menu for Tools -> Wizards -> Upsizing?

It prompts you through a variety of dialogs asking for what database do you want to send to SQL, which SQL to connect to (create connection handle if so needed),  and which tables you want to upload.

Depending, you could upload everything into a temporary database and then pull into a final production database depending on your needs.  Or just import to a new database you have ready for the incoming data.

Comment: Yes, I have looked through Upsizing Wizard, but after adding the dbf file its showing me the error that "Unable to open the file"

Comment: @AniketPanke, if you have any users that have the app open and that is preventing some exclusive use, that could make it fail... it's been like 10 yrs since I had to do an upsizing.  Try to make sure "SET EXCLUSIVE OFF".  If you added the tables to a database for the purposes of the upsizing, make sure to "CLOSE ALL" too.  If it still fails, try to provide more detail of where / phase of the upsizing it stopped at.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I have looked through Upsizing Wizard, but after adding the dbf
>   file its showing me the error that "Unable to open the file"

First question - what language are you using for your application?
* VFP?
* Something else?

Additionally you have not mentioned how you are attempting to access the file.
* Using 'standard' VFP data table commands?
* Using an ODBC Connection to the SQL Server?
        http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/How-to-Connect-to-a-SQL-Server-from-Visual-FoxPro/

Let us understand your situation better and we can make better suggestions.